# Issue with the click series Button using hightchart

Tags: highcharts

I have the problem with the hightcharts as below, I have 3 buttons at the bottom which are MGO, RMG380 and RMG500. When clicking on the button of MGO and RMG380, it will show the respective line chart, how to make the button RMG500 click to show the line chart together with the line chart of RMG380?

```
Link as below - http://jsfiddle.net/wL8d7x7u/
```

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/8xgf0LLt/ if it helps

Comment: As per your question from today, this is also off-topic, because it is not mostly self-contained - please read [ask]. Would you also edit the essence of the code into the question here as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://jsfiddle.net/wL8d7x7u/5/.

I think you asked to show both lines RMG500 and RMG380 when RMG500 is selected.

To do so I just added a code on series event function.

```
if(this.name=='RMG500'){
  var index =  _.findKey(this.chart.series,
                   function(o) {return o.name === 'RMG380'});
    this.chart.series[index].show();
   }
```

I have used **lodash** library to find the index of 'RMG380' in the series array.
After having that index, I just called show() on it.

In order to use lodash library you need to import it see [Lodash](https://lodash.com/). I have added its CDN ,see scripts in html file.

However if you don't wan't use lodash then just iterate over this.chart.series and get its key. Or if you want to show all series on click of RMG500 then simply iterate over **this.chart.series** and call **show()** on every series.

Comment: Thank Satish for the solution, just to ask when I open the jsfiddle it is still showing the same code? Did you forgot to save it?

Comment: Sorry I did forget. I have updated the link in the answer.